# Select option sort last option become first

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a fix select html. How to change fix select option and make last option become first option automatically using `jQuery`

```
<select class="terms" id="128035">

    <option class="term" id="1">ans1</option>
    <option class="term" id="2">ans2</option>
    <option class="term" id="-1">-- Please Select --</option>

</select>
```

What i need is to change please select all become first choice. i read using reverse but still not working. If anyone can help.

```
<select class="terms" id="128035">

       <option class="term" id="-1">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option class="term" id="1">ans1</option>
        <option class="term" id="2">ans2</option>

    </select>
```

Comment: Sorting should be on load? or should be on some click?

Comment: Why not change the markup, rather than having javascript patch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#128035 option[id="-1"]').insertBefore('#128035 option:first');

$("#128035").val($("#128035 option:first").val());
```

The first line moves the `option` with `id` = `-1` to before the first `option`

The second line sets the first `option` as `selected`.

```js
$('#128035 option[id="-1"]').insertBefore('#128035 option:first');

$("#128035").val($("#128035 option:first").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="terms" id="128035">

    <option class="term" id="1">ans1</option>
    <option class="term" id="2">ans2</option>
    <option class="term" id="-1">-- Please Select --</option>

</select>
```

Option 2

```js
$('#128035 option[id="-1"]').insertBefore('#128035 option[id="1"]');

$("#128035").val($("#128035 option:first").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="terms" id="128035">

    <option class="term" id="1">ans1</option>
    <option class="term" id="2">ans2</option>
    <option class="term" id="-1">-- Please Select --</option>

</select>
```

Comment: $('.terms option[id="-1"]').insertBefore('.terms option[id="1"]');

Comment: @airi I thanks for your support, but I don't agree, I think its better to make it as dynamic as possible, that's why i use `:first`

Comment: if you want me to accept it , the answer is like comment before.. you know some website is complicated how it goes. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I've added your suggestion to the code, then both examples remain

Answer (score 1):

What the code below does is remembering the node, then places in the needed position while removing it from parent node as a part of prepend function logic.

```js
var last = $('#-1')
$('#128035').prepend(last)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="terms" id="128035">

    <option class="term" id="1">ans1</option>
    <option class="term" id="2">ans2</option>
    <option class="term" id="-1">-- Please Select --</option>

</select>
```

You can also do it without jQuery with selected attribute. Just place this line wherever inside select block.

`<option selected="selected">-- Select me--</option>`

Also worth noticing that it's not recommended to use plain numbers as id's for HTML elements. Make it `id="a1"`, `id="a2"` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use [:first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/),[:last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/) and [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/). Try this:

```js
  $("select option:first").before($("select option:last")); //this will move last option before first option.
$("select option:first").attr("selected",true); //this will select first option by default.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="terms" id="128035">
    <option class="term" id="1">ans1</option>
    <option class="term" id="2">ans2</option>
    <option class="term" id="-1">-- Please Select --</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var options = $('#128035 option');
    $(options[2]).insertBefore( $( options[ 0 ] ) );
    $("#128035").val($("#128035 option:first").val());
});
```

Inserting with insertBefore or insertAfter is quite easy, and then you only have to set your first option the default value to your select.

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hj7vL9xy/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:last` and `:first` to get your last option to been seen as first option.

In my code below, `:last` will get the last option and `:first` is used to `insertBefore` first option:

```js
$('#128035 option:last').insertBefore('#128035 option:first');
$('#128035').val($('#128035 option:first').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="terms" id="128035">

    <option class="term" id="1">ans1</option>
    <option class="term" id="2">ans2</option>
    <option class="term" id="-1">-- Please Select --</option>

</select>
```